# JNI: Native library requires void*, how can I convert my jbytearray to C void*

Tags: java, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Here is what I have so far:

**Java:**

`public static native String  getConfigName(byte[] array);`

**C:**  (the code below returns a dummy value for compilation)

```
jstring Java_com_example_plugin_HelloJni_getConfigName( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray array )
{

    // get jbyte array from array and it's length
    jbyte* bufferPtr = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
    jsize lengthOfArray = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);

    // Code I need to run using void* and size_t
    dlpspec_scan_read_configuration (   void *  pBuf, const size_t  bufSize )

    // release array
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, bufferPtr, 0);

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI");
}
```

How can I convert this jbyte* to a void* would it be a simple (void*) cast? also what about the jsize to size_t conversion? this is my first time using JNI and the Android NDK. Thanks

Comment: You never need to cast anything to `void*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I convert this jbyte* to a void* would it be a simple (void*) cast?

Assuming that you want to pass the data it points to as-is, yes. Or just pass your `jbyte*` to `dlpspec_scan_read_configuration` without any casting. Either way it's your responsibility to make sure that it's the correct type of data for `dlpspec_scan_read_configuration` (e.g. if your function expects a `void*` to an ASCII string but you pass it a `void*` to a Unicode string then you probably wouldn't get the desired result).

> what about the jsize to size_t conversion

`jsize` is an alias for `jint`, which is a signed 32-bit integer type. `size_t` on the other hand is an unsigned integer type of unspecified size. So you should check that your `jsize` is in the range `0..SIZE_MAX`. If it is, you can cast it to a `size_t`. If it isn't, it's up to you what you want to do (clamp the value, return an error, abort the program, ...).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The function is supposed to take in a buffer pointing to tpl serialized binary of the scan config data structure. So I think I'll be good to go. more info on tpl: https://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/